# convert file to captial and move lines to array

Tags: c

I have txt file written in english. I need to convert all the charts to capital letter and then split it every \n and put it in array.

anyone know some commands I can use to make it easy?

example: `txt file = "I have \n five Apples"-->` `A=[I HAVE, FIVE APPLES]`

*I write the code in C*

tnx for help

Answer (score 0):

in c use strtok.
usage and example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

for uppercase use maybe toupper() for each char but char-'a'+'A' might be simpler/faster